# Preciso fazer um exercício no qual tenho que separar as palavras digitadas pelo usuário e mostrar quantas palavras foram repetidas (com o map())

Tags: java, map

Pesquisei várias coisas sobre map mas ainda estou muito perdido em como fazer isso. Alguém pode me ajudar?
Logo abaixo estão os métodos que utilizei.

```
public void lerTexto() {
    System.out.println("Digite um texto: ");
    texto = sc.nextLine();
}

public void separaTexto() {
    lerTexto();
    Map<String, Integer> mapear = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    String [] palavras = texto.split(" ");
    
    for (int i = 0; i < palavras.length; i++) {
        mapear.put(palavras[i], i);
    }
    
    for (String chave: mapear.keySet()) {
        System.out.println(chave + ": " + mapear.get(chave));
    }
    
    for (int i = 0; i < palavras.length; i++) {
        if (mapear.get(palavras) == null) {
            mapear.put(palavras[i], i);
        } else {
            mapear.put(palavras[i], i + mapear.get(palavras[i]));
        }
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No primeiro `for`, você está percorrendo o array de palavras e associando cada palavra ao seu índice dentro do mapa. Se a idéia é mostrar as palavras repetidas, você deve associar cada palavra a uma **contagem** e não ao próprio índice `i`.

Essa contagem deve iniciar em 0 e ser incrementada em 1 sempre que a mesma palavra for encontrada no mapa.

Uma forma de implementar essa contagem é usando o método `getOrDefault(chave, valorPadrao)`, que retorna o valor associado a uma chave, ou um valor padrão caso essa chave ainda não esteja cadastrada. No seu caso, se uma palavra não está cadastrada significa que a contagem dela ainda não começou e o valor padrão deve ser igual a 0:

```java
Map<String, Integer> mapear = new HashMap<>();
String [] palavras = texto.split(" ");

for (int i = 0; i < palavras.length; i++) {
    String palavraAtual = palavras[i];
    Integer contagem = mapear.getOrDefault(palavraAtual, 0);
    mapear.put(palavraAtual, contagem + 1);
}
```

As palavras repetidas são aquelas para as quais o valor da contagem é maior que 1:

```java
System.out.println("Palavras Repetidas:");
for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entrada : mapear.entrySet()) {
    if (entrada.getValue() > 1) {
        System.out.println(entrada.getKey());
    }
}
```